# How to set and use cookies right away in the same request to the koa server?

Tags: express, cookies, koa

I can successfully set cookies on the koa server. Is there a way to use these cookies in the same request? I am fine to issue a second request with the set cookies, but do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get the cookie client side or server side?  If it is client side, you could just pass ctx to the view and then you would have ctx.cookies.  If it is server side, then you just have ctx as a parameter in whatever endpoint is being called.  ctx is passed with every request, so you should always have the cookies.